# resuming activity in Android using Service

Tags: android, service, oncreate, resume

I have a `mainActivity`.
When starts, it starts a service and bonds it.
There is a timer which will send the `mainActivity` (this) to back after X seconds, while the service keep running and listening, i use `moveTaskToBack (true)`.
When the service listener triggered, the service starts the activity, but instead of the activity to be called through `onResume()` (since it was sent to back) its called through `onCreate()`, to call the activity currently i use :

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Which explains why the activity is created all over again.
I tried using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` but got an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this attribute in activity of AndroidManifest.xml `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in AndroidManitest.xml

AndroidMenifest.xml

```
 <application>
        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"> 
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: to what ? the mainActivity part ? isn't it just going to 'kill' and 'recreate' the activity but not resuming it ?

Comment: When is service started, from where??

Comment: Try to confirm onpause() gets called.when movetasktoback(true); is invoked

Comment: @Arju , the service is started from the mainActivity `onCreate()`

Comment: before starting the activity from service set FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag for intent.e.g intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: @Kirit , i checked your suggestion and i get the same unwanted behavior.

Comment: please add your logcat output

Comment: @Kirit , in the logcat i can see only my messages (i added, 'in onResume', 'in onCreate' etc...) i don't see there anything else which can help.